# What happens on JVM crash on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos, operating-system

What I want to know - what files are created when Java Virtual Mashine crashes on Mac, and where they can be found?

Are they are hs_err_pid* files at home directory, like on win/linux, or mac os does it the other way?

Answer (score 1):

It creates a hs_err_pid*.log file (this comes from "HotSpot error" log). About the location of the file:

1. you can specify it by starting the java process with JVM param -XX:ErrorFile=some_path
2. if you don't specify it, the location is not very deterministic; the JVM prints something on STDOUT (usually the main error message), and the details are written to hs_err_pid.log file in the current directory, in the current user's temp directory (if no there are no write permissions for the current directory) or simply at stdout

So you can search it in the temp file (if you want to trace an older JVM crash), but it's a good idea to specify the file as a JVM param.